# Why the odd-even cases differ?

Tags: isabelle

In this exercise `auto` proves the `even_mul` lemma while it fails to prove  `odd_mul`.

```
fun is_odd :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
    "is_odd n = (n mod 2 ≠ 0)"

fun is_even :: "nat ⇒ bool" where
    "is_even n = (n mod 2 = 0)"

lemma even_mul : "is_even (n::nat) ⟹ is_even (n * n)"
  by auto

lemma odd_mul : "is_odd (n::nat) ⟹ is_odd (n * n)"
  by auto
```

I'd appreciate an explanation on how the two cases differ, and hints on how to prove `odd_mul`, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prove `odd_mul` by adding the lemma `mod2_eq_if` to the simplification rules as follows:

```
lemma odd_mul : "is_odd (n::nat) ⟹ is_odd (n * n)"
  by (simp add: mod2_eq_if)
```

To understand why the `auto` method proves `even_mul` but fails to prove `odd_mul`, let's have a look at the respective simplifier traces (only the relevant parts are shown). The trace for `even_mul` is shown below:

```
...
[1]Rewriting:
is_even (n * n) ≡ n * n mod 2 = 0 
[1]Applying instance of rewrite rule "Rings.semidom_modulo_class.dvd_imp_mod_0":
?a1 dvd ?b1 ⟹ ?b1 mod ?a1 ≡ 0 
[1]Trying to rewrite:
even (n * n) ⟹ n * n mod 2 ≡ 0 
[2]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
even (n * n) 
[2]Applying instance of rewrite rule "Parity.semiring_parity_class.even_mult_iff":
even (?a1 * ?b1) ≡ even ?a1 ∨ even ?b1 
[2]Rewriting:
even (n * n) ≡ even n ∨ even n 
...
```

We can see that the simplifier is able to use the rewrite rule `even (?a1 * ?b1) ≡ even ?a1 ∨ even ?b1` from the `Parity` theory because the definitions of `even` and `is_even` turn out to be the same when rewriting `even` using `dvd_imp_mod_0` from `Rings.semidom_modulo_class`.

However, this is not the case for `odd` and `is_odd`, since `odd a ≡ ¬ 2 dvd a` and the simplifier cannot rewrite it to use `is_odd` without additional help from the user, as shown in the output panel:

```
theorem odd_mul: is_odd ?n ⟹ is_odd (?n * ?n) 
Failed to finish proof⌂:
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. n mod 2 = Suc 0 ⟹ n * n mod 2 = Suc 0
```

However, in the proof of `odd_mul` at the top of this post, we explicitly provide the additional rewrite rule `mod2_eq_if` to help the simplifier bridge the gap between `odd` and `is_odd` as shown in the trace below:

```
...
[1]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
is_odd n ⟹ is_odd (n * n) 
[1]Applying instance of rewrite rule "??.unknown":
is_odd ?n1 ≡ ?n1 mod 2 ≠ 0 
[1]Rewriting:
is_odd n ≡ n mod 2 ≠ 0 
[1]Applying instance of rewrite rule "Parity.semiring_parity_class.mod2_eq_if":
?x1 mod 2 ≡ if even ?x1 then 0 else 1 
[1]Rewriting:
n mod 2 ≡ if even n then 0 else 1 
[1]Applying congruence rule:
even n ≡ ?c ⟹ if even n then 0 else 1 ≡ if ?c then 0 else 1 
[2]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
even n ≡ ?c 
[1]SUCCEEDED
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer, Javier; it's very helpful.